# Python Package in module call function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

First of all sorry if this is a very simplet question. I have a PyPi project with the following structure:

```
foo-->bar.py
foo-->__init__.py
setup.py
```

bar.py has the following contents

```
def somefunction(a,b):
     Do something with a,b
```

To call the function and use it I have to use something like the following:

```
import foo.bar as something
something.somefunction(x,y)
```

Typically in a module you don't have to use such long calls, I'd like to shorten it to something like this:

```
from foo import bar
bar(x,y)
```

I know it is something quite simple but not quite grasping it. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to do `from foo import somefunction`? In your example `bar` is a module, not a function. You will not be able to call it like you do in your last example.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `bar` to be a function, and not a module, you need to move `somefunction` into `__init__.py` and rename it:

`__init__.py`:

```py
def bar(a,b):
    '''Do something with a,b'''
    pass
```

Then you can do:

```py
from foo import bar
bar(x,y)
```